# Google analytics does not work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-analytics

I found there was no IE visitor in google analytics report of my site.

I wrote a simple test page and confirmed that IE did not send '__utm.gif' request to google server. But it worked fine in other browsers, for example FF and Chrome. The test page is: http://k.ai/haiseepage.html

I doubt if it is because the domain name 'k.ai'. I test almost the same page in other .com site. The .com site is ok.

Anyone can explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSIE doesn't set cookies on very short domain names (2 or less chars)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310676 .

This is why Google Analytics doesn't work on your domain

You should try using this instead

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.k.ai']);
```

But beware that doing so will reset the cookies of all your previous visitors on other browsers (they all will be new visitors and lose their previous source of visit).

Comment: Actually you can do activate this settings only for IE visitors, using HTML conditional comments.
Thus it will affect only IE users (which are not tracked until now) and will not affect others (then no cookie reset: data is preserved)

Answer (score 0):

No DOCTYPE is probably tripping up IE. Instead of `<html>` put:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You may also want to add to the `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```